# Focus en una celda - Jtable

Tags: java

Al momento que selecciono cualquier celda se selecciona toda la fila, lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione cualquier celda se enfoque esa celda de un color y así con las demás, ojo que siga la selección de toda la fila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso debes hacerte un render a medida y ponérselo a todas las columnas que quieras que tengan ese comportamiento. El código para el render sería:

```
TableCellRenderer render = new TableCellRenderer() {

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
       boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component c = table.getDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(column))
       .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if(hasFocus)
       ((JComponent)c).setBackground(Color.GREEN);//Pones el color que quieras

    return c;
  }

});
```

Comment: ya implemente el codigo pero me pinta toda la fila y no la celda que selecciono

Comment: @Leandro he editado la respuesta para cambiar la condición para el pintado a `hasFocus`. Prueba de nuevo para ver si es lo que buscas.

Comment: ya lo edite, cuando selecciono cualquier celda se enfoca esa celda de color negro pero el problema es que cuando selecciono otra celda, la seleccion anterior se pinta todo de negro

Comment: Entonces debes añadir que si la condición es `!hasFocus` le pongas el color que usas para el resto. Deberías leer la documentación de Java sobre el [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) para que puedas experimentar por tu cuenta. Si pones el fondo negro supongo que querrás poner las letras blancas para leerlas o algo así. Haciendote un render a la carta puedes manejar todas esas cosas, así como lo que se lee en la celda o el formato que tendrá un decimal por ejemplo @Leandro .